# Queueing file uploads with Promise.map

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

The first set of files is uploaded successfully, but as soon as it is done, it does not start the next set in the queue.

Why does the iteration stop after the first set and how do I fix this issue?

*The solution does not have to use Bluebird necessarily – I used it in the first place, because I thought, I would turn out to be easier.*

```
function uploadFile(url, file, onProgress) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', url);

        xhr.addEventListener('readyState', _ => {
            if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                resolve(file);
            }
        });

        xhr.addEventListener('error', _ => {
            reject(new Error());
        });

        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', event => {
            onProgress && onProgress(event.loaded / event.total);
        });

        xhr.send(formData);

    });

}

/* files is a FileList */
Promise.map(Array.from(files), file => {
    return uploadFile(location.href, file, null);
}, { concurrency: 2 });
```

Comment: Do you want the uploads to be sequential, or in parallel?

Comment: I want to upload 2 files in parallel.

Comment: My first inclination would be to check your resolve is actually being called.

Comment: You can use `addEventListener('load', callback)` instead of `readyState`.  Also `readyState` will be `xhr.DONE`  on any response eg `500`, `400`. so you will always need to do checking there.

Comment: Ok, as it turns out, the event type is called "readystatechange" and not "readyState" ... it is working now – it looked so right

Comment: Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event type is called `readystatechange` (not `readyState`).

As powerc9000 noticed in the comments, the Promise does not get resolved and Promise.map does not know when to continue.